# jQuery plugin for a JavaScript garden style table of contents?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tableofcontents

I love the [jQuery Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/) table of contents. The are lots of jQuery plugins that generate an automated table of contents but are there any that provide active section highlighting and respond to the screen height like this one does?

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting here: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/javascript/garden.js.  Love this effect, hopefully will report back w findings!

Answer (score 0):

I just released [Tocify](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.tocify.js/), a jQuery Table of Contents plugin.  Although I do not do section highlighting currently, I would be happy to include that if you create an issue on Github.